# C++: Constructor versus initializer list in struct/class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, struct, initializer-list

An object of a struct/class (that has no **constructor**) can be created using an **initializer list**. Why is this not allowed on struct/class with **constructor**?

```
struct r { int a; };
struct s { int a; s() : a(0) {} };
r = { 1 }; // works
s = { 1 }; // does not work
```

Comment: Post some code that illustrates what you are asking about.

Comment: Neil, answer made sense to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, an object with a constructor is no longer considered a POD (plain old data). Objects must only contain other POD types as non-static members (including basic types). A POD can have static functions and static complex data members.

Note that the upcoming C++ standard will allow you to define initializer lists, which will allow non-POD objects to be initialized with braces.

Answer (score 0):

If by your question you mean to ask, "Can I do this:"

```
struct MyGizmo
{
  char things_[5];
  MyGizmo() : things_({'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}) ();
};
```

...then the answer is no.  C++ doesn't allow this.

Comment: No, initializing an array of chars is different from initializing a POD struct that can contain variables of different types. Also, you're doing it the ctor, the OP asked for initialization on an object that has a defined ctor.

Comment: actually, g++ has a heck to do that, not standard: (char[1]){ 0 }