# Clarification of use of structs with Arduino and storing structs in PROGMEM

Tags: c, arduino

*(Because of the limited memory available on most Arduino boards, I've sometimes run into problems using valid C/C++ code, so this question is specifically about any issues on using structs on Arduino.)*

I've seen [example code of using structs in Arduino](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/ResourceFriendlyStructs) but no discussion of memory reqs.

1. Is the size of a struct simply the sum of the data types of its fields?
2. Is storing structs in PROGMEM an option? Are there access speed issues?
3. Are the fields of a struct writable (e.g. example below `s1.LED1.state = 0;`) (though not if stored in PROGMEM, of course).
4. Can I define a field of a struct as another (different type) struct?
5. Is it possible to iterate through a struct using `for..in` or by index?

My use case is that I have 64 LEDs driven by a MAX7219 chip. Because of the requirements of the physical wiring layout, it would be convenient to organize the LED order in a more logical way using structs in order to make the programming easier/more coherent.

---

```
  typedef struct {
      byte row : 6;
      byte col : 128;
      byte state : 1;
    } LED;
```

---

```
 typedef struct {
      LED LED1 : {1,1,1};
      LED LED2 : {1,2,1};
      LED LED3 : {1,4,1};
      LED LED4 : {1,8,1};
      LED LED5 : {1,16,1};
      LED LED6 : {1,32,1};
      LED LED7 : {1,64,1};
      LED LED8 : {1,128,1};
    } LED_SECTION;
```

---

```
LED_SECTION s1;
s1.LED1.row = 1;
```

---

```
 s1.LED1.state = 0;
```

Comment: Interesting, never seen that 'width' notation for structs :) Should `byte` not be `LED` in the `LED_SECTION` struct?

Comment: Also, a `byte` with 128 bits? What is this madness?

Comment: @leppie - yes. copy/paste error. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: A byte in Arduino: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Byte

Comment: `byte col : 128;` is declaring a '`byte`' with 128 bits! The suffix is not the maximum value, it is the bitcount.

Comment: Not sure if gcc does this, but something like `struct LED { int enabled : 1; }; typedef struct LED[6][128] MATRIX;` should provide the minimum size. Though that is way more than 64 LED's. You just need a 64-bit integer (`long long` should do) to store the state of all 64 LED's.

Comment: @leppie - This is confusing. The example code I link to (http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/ResourceFriendlyStructs) uses that syntax to define the value of a struct member, not a typedef for a byte. (or maybe I am more confused than I thought ;-)

Comment: In that example `pin` has 6 bits, so 64 possible values (read pin address). To store the pin address is redundant in my opinion (unless you want some kind of address translation).

Comment: @leppie - ok, I've dug around a little more and see my error. I thought I could define default values in my struct and that that was what the Arduino example code is doing. Apparently that is not possible in C (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6193328/840992)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When using the semi-colon syntax, the size of the struct will be the sum of all its fields.
2. I think its possible using this syntax: (http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM)

   > ```
   > LED leds PROGMEM;
   > ```
3. Yes they are, the syntax is as you wrote in your question.
4. Yes you may:

   > typedef struct {
   >      struct otherStruct; };
5. Yes you can do that using masks. For example:

   > ```
   > for (int i = 0, byte cur = s1 & 1; ; i < numOfFieldsInStruct; i++, cur = (s1<<i)&1) {
   >     ....
   > }
   > ```

Regarding your last comment to this answer, let me propose the following solution:

Organize the leds in a way that addressing them won't take up memory (like in the question - the LED struct takes memory for addressing). Instead, you can address the leds using their position in an array and in the struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
    byte LED1 : 1;
    byte LED2 : 1;
    byte LED3 : 1;
    byte LED4 : 1;
    byte LED5 : 1;
    byte LED6 : 1;
    byte LED7 : 1;
    byte LED8 : 1;
} LED_ROW;

LED_ROW leds[256];

leds[0].LED1 = 1; // turn led at row 0, col 0 to 1
leds[0].LED5 = 1; // turn led at row 4, col 0 to 1
led[100].LED3 = 1; // turn led at row 2, col 100 to 1
...
// and so on
```

You may consider arranging the array differently, with 256 items in the struct and 8 items in the array so the rows will be refered to by [] and the cols after the dot, like so:

```
leds[0].LED3 = 1; // turn on led at row 0, col 2 to 1
```

Comment: thanks! A detail: is the `&1` in `(s1<<i)&1` referencing the memory address of struct instance `s1`? What is this type of operation called so I can read up on it. I understand the bitshifting part, just not the `&1`

Comment: in order to provide the best answer for your question, could you please tell me what do you need the row and col definition for in the led struct?

Comment: In my project, the LEDs are controlled by a 8x8 multiplexor chip (MAXIM7219). In order to address individual LEDs, I need to know their row (e.g register 1-8). The 7219 uses bit values for column addresses (1-256). So I need to store at least two values: register and bitmask. Since I will use PROGMEM for this, if I need to store state, I would use some sort of dynamic array.

Comment: I edited the answer to include a solution sugestion for your problem. Let me know if it fits your needs or not, or if you have another question :)