# C++: Use memset or a struct constructor? What's the fastest?

Tags: c++, constructor, struct, initialization, performance

I'm having trouble figuring out which is better in C++:

I use a struct to manage clients in a message queue, the struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct _MsgClient {
  int handle;
  int message_class;
  void *callback;
  void *private_data;
  int priority;
} MsgClient;
```

All of these being POD entities.

Now, I have an array of these structs where I store my clients (I use an array for memory constraints, I have to limit fragmentation). So in my class I have something like this:

```
class Foo
{
private:
  MsgClient _clients[32]; 

public:
  Foo()
  {
     memset(_clients, 0x0, sizeof(_clients));
  }

}
```

Now, I read here and there on SO that using memset is bad in C++, and that I'd rather use a constructor for my structure.
I figured something like this:

```
typedef struct _MsgClient {
  int handle;
  int message_class;
  void *callback;
  void *private_data;
  int priority;
  // struct constructor
  _MsgClient(): handle(0), message_class(0), callback(NULL), private_data(NULL), priority(0) {};
} MsgClient;
```

...would eliminate the need of the `memset`. But my fear is that when foo is initialized, the struct constructor will be called 32 times, instead of optimizing it as a simple zero out of the memory taken by the array.

What's your opinion on this?
I just found this: [Can a member struct be zero-init from the constructor initializer list without calling memset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816752/can-a-member-struct-be-zero-init-from-the-constructor-initializer-list-without-ca) , is it appropriate in my case (which is different: I have an array, not a single instance of the structure)?
Also, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095759/c-constructor-versus-initializer-list-in-struct-class), adding a constructor to my structure will automatically convert it into a non-POD structure, is it right?

Comment: I can't answer the entire question, but yes, adding a custom constructor to either a struct or class will make it a non-POD structure.

Comment: +1 Its an interesting question - although even if you had an array of 100 million _clients I doubt using the constructor will cause performance issues.  And initialising each type appropriately rather than just zeroing memory is the safest thing to do. But I too would be interested to know what c++ implementations do behind the scenes in terms of initialation - whether they actually call memset anyway.

Comment: Just so you know, if you put a virtual function in this class, `memset` will effectively screw it up.

Comment: @Nicol: yeah that's what I understood by looking at the other similar questions. I wouldn't use memset AND a constructor, for me they are exclusive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On a conforming implementation, it's perfectly valid to *value-initialize* an array in the constructor initializer list with an empty member initializer. For your array members, this will have the effect of *zero-initializing* the members of each array element.

The compiler should be able to make this very efficient and there's no need for you to add a constructor to your `struct`.

E.g.

```
Foo() : _clients() {}
```

Comment: Yeap, and this will likely be implemented via `memset()` anyway - no need to think about portability, the compiler will think of how to do it best.

Comment: +1: Though I would want to actually test this by looking at the assembly output in a case where the compiler is forced to assume that the initialized values will be used.

Comment: Visual C++ >2005 counts as "conforming" for this particular case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ywe7hcy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx .

Comment: Allright, this construction seems to work, compiling-wise. I'll test it further on but I feel this is the good thing to do :)

Comment: Now hold on. Can you find a paragraph in the standard which defines this behaviour? Because I am sure it is not the case for gcc. As far as I know, object of POD type if initialized this way contain garbage

Comment: @VJo: Try 8.5 [dcl.init] for a description of _value-initialization_, 12.6.2 [class.base.init] / 3 for a description of initialization of bases and members. gcc has been conforming for ages (for ever?).

Comment: Interesting. I was wrong (that makes what you wrote right ;). This works even on gcc. I must have mixed it with POD objects creation, which do gets filled with garbage.

Answer (score 3):

You can you `memset` freely even in C++, as long as **you understand what you are doing**.
About the performance - the only way to see which way is really faster is to build your program in release configuration, and then see in the disassembler the code generated.

Using `memset` sounds somewhat faster than per-object initialization. However there's a chance the compiler will generated the same code.

Comment: Just a point of pedantry: That sentence should be: "*The only way to see why way is faster ... and then compare them by profiling.*" Looking at the disassembler won't necessarily be the easiest way of determining which is faster.